# Interest rate risk. Books recommendation

Tags: fixed-income, books

Can anyone suggest me some good books for Interest Rate risk and Credit Spread, credit spread duration?

I am new to finance so a book focussed on basics will be more helpful.

Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://quant.stackexchange.com/questions/36500/what-are-some-of-the-best-textbooks-on-fixed-income-securities/36509#36509

Answer (score 1):

Good starting point, first book I was given when I started as an intern on a bond desk - [https://www.amazon.com/Inside-Yield-Book-Classic-Analysis/dp/111839013X](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/111839013X) "Inside the Yield Book".